# SignalR performance counters in Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net, azure, signalr, performancecounter, azure-web-app-service

I've been trying to load test SignalR on my Azure Web App service (E.g. how many connections it can handle before subscribe calls to the hub start failing). I found that SignalR perfomance counters (https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-performance ) can provide me such info. However, I cannot install those performance counters on Web App service, buy running

> SignalR.exe ipc

Is there a way to install those performance counters on WebApp or retrieve them somehow from code?

Answer (score 0):

Performance Counters [can't be installed on Azure Web App](http://stackify.com/top-3-azure-web-app-limitations/), as it is provided as a managed container and **not** a full fledged IIS on which you can do everything.

To be able to use these performance counters you can redeploy your solution on an Azure VM or to a Cloud Service, keeping in mind you will **loose the flexibility** that Azure Web App offers.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose the SignalR performance counters in an Azure Web App using a **WebRole**, as stated in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/performance/using-signalr-performance-counters-in-an-azure-web-role)